# How to install 32 bit Android Studio on 64 bit Windows?

Tags: android, android-studio

The download page at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other doesn't show any explicit 32 vs 64 bit downloads, so I'm guessing the installer automatically installs the 64 bit version on 64 bit systems. Is there any way to override this?

Comment: @DerGolem Are you sure? There are two executables, `studio.exe` and `studio64.exe`

Answer (score 9):

Since most of Android Studio is written in Java, there isn't much difference between the 64 and 32-bit versions, only the launcher and some DLLs.

In any case:

- `<android-studio>\bin\studio.exe` is the 32-bit launcher.
- `<android-studio>\bin\studio64.exe` is the 64-bit launcher.

However, the 32-bit launcher cannot actually be started in a x64 Windows installation (it will complain about this fact, and close itself).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, had assumed there would be two separate installations, like with Eclipse... The problem I have is that the 64 bit launcher exits if no 64 bit JVM is found; I was hoping there would be a way to get Android Studio to use one of my existing 32 bit Java SDKs, instead of having to add another one.

Comment: Using Studio v1.2.1.1 on 64-bit Windows and 32-bit JDK, and 32-bit Studio version runs just fine. Thanks for the tip!